# Unable to activate Nvidia GPU in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a Nvidia GTX 1650ti GPU and Ubuntu 20.04 (dual booted) in my system. However, when I check the "graphics" option in settings, it shows "AMD Renoir" instead of the dedicated GPU (Thus applications like Gazebo and the system in general is running relatively slowly).

"NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" is selected in NVIDIA X Server Settings and on running `prime-select query` it also shows nvidia. In the "additional drivers" tab in Software and Updates, it shows that nvidia-driver-510 is being used. I have tried reinstalling the drivers using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but still am facing the same issue. How can I select the Nvidia GPU?

Edit: Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.41.0, 5.13.0-39-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` command.

Comment: Updated the question with the output of the advised command

Comment: The system really doesn't use Nvidia. There is a problem with `nvidia-prime` with AMD integrated GPUs. I can't advise on that.

Comment: Perhaps you can disable the Renoir in the UEFI Settings/BIOS and then the Nvidia GPU will be used.

Comment: How can I disable renoir in UEFI settings? Also, I have Ubuntu 22.04 (and windows 11) in the same system and that uses the nvidia gpu